# webots 2020a-rev1 snap controller matlab problem Ubuntu 18.04.3

Tags: matlab, webots

I installed the snap version of webots 2020a-rev1 in Ubuntu 18.04.3.
I have to define controllers as extern. But how does webots know which kind of language is used for controller?

Maybe the problem is related with another post which defines that matlab controller was working for 2019a but not for 2020a?

Thanks for reply

Comment: Neither your problem is clear nor does it help if you speculate without providing the posts. It would also be good to post the matlab release that your are using.

Comment: Yes, MATLAB support is indeed broken in Webots R2020-rev1. Webots doesn't need to know what language is used for a controller, controllers are communicating with Webots through a system pipe. So, it's not language dependent.